# Unable to call class or method from another package (force close)

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

In the whole project whenever i try to call any method or class in another  class between packages 
NoSuchMethod or NoSuchClass or NosuchActivity error occurred.
But all methods and classes that I'm calling do exist.
Same code is working on my another android project. Don't what issue is happing in this.

here is my code

```
public interface ApiHolder {

    @GET("login_api.php")
    Call<LoginResponse> loginuser(@Field("username") String username,
                                  @Field("passwrd") String passwrd,
                                  @Field("key") String key);

}
```

Another class method where I'm calling above method

```
public void validateUser(String user, String pass, String imei) {
        ApiHolder get_list = ServiceConnection.getClient().create(ApiHolder.class);
        Call<LoginResponse> call = get_list.loginuser(user, pass, K.Url.urlkey);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<LoginResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<LoginResponse> call, Response<LoginResponse> response) {
                   lr = response.body().getLoginData();

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<LoginResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                t.printStackTrace();
                Log.e("***failure***", t.toString());

                //pDialog.dismiss();

            }
        });

    }
```

and the logcat showing this error

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: Process: sample.co.in, PID:java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
 No interface method loginuser(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Lretrofit2/Call; in class Lsample/co/in/webservice/ApiHolder; or its super classes (declaration of 'sample.co.in.webservice.ApiHolder' appears in /data/data/sample.co.in/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_7-classes.dex)
                                                                                   at eon.co.rdcconcrete.LoginActivity.validateUser(LoginActivity.java:199)
                                                                                    at eon.co.rdcconcrete.LoginActivity$1.onClick(LoginActivity.java:106)
                                                                                        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5207)
                                                                                        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21177)
                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:742)
                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5529)
                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:739)
                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:629)
```

manifest.class

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="sample.co.in">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/rdc_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".DPRMainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">

    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Please make sure. If you calling activity. It must be declare in manifest.xml file.

Comment: you got to rebuild your project, its may be instant run feature making issue here

Comment: clean and rebuild project many times but uninstalling and run works thanks @vikaskumar

Comment: Invalidate Cache / Restart (Or) clean and build it again and check

Answer (score 0):

If you are testing this code on emulator with android 6 then don't forget to **grant runtime permissions**.

the above error occurred may be due to permissions so do check in app info that permission granted or not...